# pip install --editable cause "running develop, error in 'egg_base' option: 'src' does not exist"

Tags: python, setuptools

I tried to install my own python application via `pip3 install --editable`. But I got an error like "`running develop, error in 'egg_base' option: 'src' does not exist`".

The project has a `src` folder layout.

```
hyperorg
├── docs
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── hyperorg
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __main__.py
│   ├── setup.cfg
│   └── setup.py
└── tests
```

I did `pip3 install --editable src` in folder `hyperorg` and `pip3 install --editable .` in folder `hyperorg/src` without a noticeable difference.

The `setup.py` just call `setuptools.setup()`.

Here are some lines from the `setup.cfg` which I build based on the [official documentatoin](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/setuptools.html).

```
[options]
package_dir=
    =src
packages = find:
zip_safe = False
install_requires =
    orgparse

[options.packages.find]
where = src
exclude =
    docs*
    tests*
    notes
    .gitignore
```

## Full error output

```
$ pip3 install --editable src
Obtaining file:///home/user/tab-cloud/hyperorg/src
Requirement already satisfied: orgparse in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from Hyperorg==0.0.0a1) (0.3.1)
Installing collected packages: Hyperorg
  Running setup.py develop for Hyperorg
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/user/tab-cloud/hyperorg/src/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/home/user/tab-cloud/hyperorg/src/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps --user --prefix=
         cwd: /home/user/tab-cloud/hyperorg/src/
    Complete output (2 lines):
    running develop
    error: error in 'egg_base' option: 'src' does not exist or is not a directory
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/user/tab-cloud/hyperorg/src/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/home/user/tab-cloud/hyperorg/src/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps --user --prefix= Check the logs for full command output.
```

I wonder what `running develop` means.

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/230 The bug is still open. Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+develop+src

Comment: `running develop` means `pip` runs `python setup.py develop`. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/commands.html#develop-deploy-the-project-source-in-development-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location of the `setup.cfg` and `setup.py` files are the problem here.

Depending on experiences with another project out of habit I located them in the `src` folder.

```
hyperorg
├── src
│   ├── hyperorg
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── setup.cfg
│   └── setup.py
```

This can work in some circumstances but the official [setuptools documentation about usage of `setup.cfg`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html) also state to locate that files in the project root like this.

```
hyperorg
├── src
│   └── ...
├── setup.cfg
└── setup.py
```

In that case my setup work like a charm without modifying any other files. I just have to do in the project root

```
pip3 install --editable .
```

The string `develop` in the error output points to a [*Development Mode*](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/commands.html#develop-deploy-the-project-source-in-development-mode) of `setuptools`. This is because of the `--editable` option in the `pip` call. The effect of *Development Mode* is that the package is not installed the usual way via coping the py files in the right directories of the system but just links to the source folders are created.

*EDIT*: This answer is still valid. But keep in mind that today the recommendation is to use a [`pyproject.toml`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html) file instead of `setup.cfg`. The details can be found in the `setuptools` docu.